# Treeview like Visual Studio 2010 toolbox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview, custom-controls

I'm looking a very similar control like the VS 2010 toolbox.

A tree view where I can have a header and my subitems. Ando also the facility to move up or down the item (or drag and drop).

Does you have idea where can I get one? I'm interested in a WPF control.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a special control.  Just apply a [`HierarchicalDataTemplate`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.aspx&ei=4m7fUN2fJoWA2AW9zoCQCQ&usg=AFQjCNF5bqK83UYRUTvbAcCzXuz25NOAnA&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.b2I) to make the layers look like you want them to.

Here's a quick [step-by-step](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2009/10/30/treeview-and-hierarchicaldatatemplate-step-by-step.aspx) on how to do so with a `TreeView`.